# Matlab: How can I put more than 2 strings of different length into one char element?

Tags: string, matlab

I would like to program a loop over a number of strings of different length. My problem is that I don't get my various strings stored in one element. I've tried the following:

```
string=['string1';'longerstring2']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
%# Store
string = {'string1','longerstring2'};
%# Access
disp(string{1});
```

Output:

> string1

Comment: Thanks, for this straightforward solution, however I was hoping that the length function would give me the number of elements not the number of strings (important to limit my loop).

Comment: I'm confused. Is this what you want: `string = ['string1' 'longerstring2']`?

Comment: @Jacob I don't have access to the Matlab IDE at the moment, but I'm pretty sure that the 'length' and 'size' functions will work fine on the 'string' cell array in this answer.

Comment: @Mike: use `cellfun` to get the length of each individual string: `cellfun(@length,string)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the strings in a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html).  The [cellstr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellstr.html) function may be useful to you for generating the cell array from a list of strings of equal length (padded with spaces), or you could just create the cell array manually.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions if you're happy with a cell array. Alternatively, you can do

```
char('string1','longerstring2')
```

which will pad with spaces, so is equivalent to (in this case):

```
['string1      ';'longerstring2']
```