# how to handle array of string?

Tags: string, matlab

Inside a Matlab function I need something like (as you can imagine in real life it should be represented as a for loop):

```
var(1) = 'First string';
var(2) = 'Second string';
...
var(i) = 'i-th string';
```

Alas, I can't do this cause var(1) should contain just a character (not an entire string) and I get:

> ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

I've searching on the web, but I can't find a good solution, any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab: How can I put more than 2 strings of different length into one char element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259368/matlab-how-can-i-put-more-than-2-strings-of-different-length-into-one-char-elem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Matlab cell array:

```
var{1} = 'first string';
var{2} = 'second string';
var{n} = 'nth string';
```